# Highly recommended books for bounded linear operators on banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, banach-spaces, book-recommendation

I am not looking for books on functional analysis in general. What I really want is highly recommended books for the theory of bounded linear operators on Banach spaces.
Not on Hilbert ones.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0603-3

Comment: [The classic reference](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Linear+Operators%2C+3+Volume+Set-p-9780470555613).

Comment: @DavidMitra Your link does not work for me, but from the URL I figure it's Dunford-Schwartz, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @DavidMitra the first volume or the third one ?

Comment: [Fabian's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=banach+space+theory+the+basis+for+linear+and+nonlinear+analysis&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIzq-ugODlAhVKILkGHQYiDukQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=banach%20space%20theory%20the%20basis%20for%20linear%20and%20nonlinear%20analysis&f=false) can be of interest.